# NUnit unable to find assembly, but console app can

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, nunit

I have a C# class which calls a [.Net assembly built from a Matlab function](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2014b/dotnetbuilder/ug/create-a-net-component-from-matlab-code.html). I am able to call this function from a simple C# console application with no problems.

However if I try to run a unit test from NUnit I get the following exception:

> ClassLibrary1.Tests.UnitTests.TestPerformOptimization:
> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been
> thrown by the target of an invocation.   ----> System.Exception :
> Error marshalling .NET object.  'Message: Unable to find assembly
> 'ClassLibrary1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null'. Source: mscorlib HelpLink: '

I get the same error if I try to call the class from either the standalone NUnit console, from ReSharper's test runner or if I try to call the function from say Excel (using Excel-DNA).

When calling my compiled Matlab component I actually wrap up a C# method (in an MWObjectArray object) and inject it in. I think the problem is happening when the compiled Matlab component tries invoking this injected method.

The only workaround I've found is to simply place a copy of my class (containing the method that is injected) in the same location as the NUnit test runner, the ReSharper test runner or Excel. However this is simply not a practical solution going forward as I need to install this application onto users machines. The other option which I can't use is copying the files to my %DEVPATH% for the same reason.

Is there a way I can tell the Matlab component where to find the assembly of my injected method/class?

**SAMPLE PROJECT DOWNLOAD**

There is a sample project available for download [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4h4vpekorltm0m5/MatLabTest.zip?dl=0). Just follow the instructions in the README.txt file located in the zip file.

**Update 1**

I manage to get my unit test to recognise my assembly by modifying my class to include the following in its constructor:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve +=
                 (sender, args) => typeof(OptimizationFunction).Assembly;
```

However now I get the following exception:

> Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has
> been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Exception:
> Error marshalling .NET object.  'Message: Could not load file or
> assembly 'dotnetcli, Version=1.0.5488.33915, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=da1231a838c93da4' or one of its dependencies. A
> strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT:
> 0x80131044) Source: mscorlib HelpLink: '    at
> dotnetcli.throwNetExceptionID(BaseMsgID* msgId)    at
> dotnetcli.DeployedDataConversion.GetMxArrayFromObject(Object data)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
> arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)

So now it has a problem resolving the dotnetclli.dll (See Fusion log/exception below) which as far as I know should reside only in C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win32.

Here's an excerpt from the Fusion Log:

> === Pre-bind state information ===
>
> LOG: DisplayName = ClassLibrary1  (Partial)
> WRN: Assembly Name: ClassLibrary1 | Domain ID: 1
> WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is  provided.
> WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
> WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
> WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token. > WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
> LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/XXXXX/ConsoleApplication1/packages/NUnit.Runners.2.6.3/tools/
> LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
> LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
> LOG: Cache Base = NULL
> LOG: AppName = nunit-agent-x86.exe
> Calling assembly : (Unknown).
>
> ===
> LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
> LOG: Using application configuration file:
> C:\Insight\TFS\Asg\ConsoleApplication4\packages\NUnit.Runners.2.6.3\tools\nunit-agent-x86.exe.Config
> LOG: Using host configuration file:  LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
> LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind). LOG: Attempting download of new URL
> file:///C:/XXXXX/ConsoleApplication4/packages/NUnit.Runners.2.6.3/tools/ClassLibrary1.DLL.
> LOG: Attempting download of new URL
> file:///C:/XXXXX/ConsoleApplication1/packages/NUnit.Runners.2.6.3/tools/ClassLibrary1/ClassLibrary1.DLL.
> LOG: Attempting download of new URL
> file:///C:/XXXXX/ConsoleApplication1/packages/NUnit.Runners.2.6.3/tools/lib/ClassLibrary1.DLL.
> LOG: Attempting download of new URL
> file:///C:/XXXXX/ConsoleApplication1/packages/NUnit.Runners.2.6.3/tools/lib/ClassLibrary1/ClassLibrary1.DLL.
> LOG: Attempting download of new URL
> file:///C:/XXXXX/ConsoleApplication1/packages/NUnit.Runners.2.6.3/tools/addins/ClassLibrary1.DLL.
> LOG: Attempting download of new URL
> file:///C:/XXXXX/ConsoleApplication1/packages/NUnit.Runners.2.6.3/tools/addins/ClassLibrary1/ClassLibrary1.DLL.
> LOG: Attempting download of new URL
> file:///C:/XXXXX/ConsoleApplication1/packages/NUnit.Runners.2.6.3/tools/ClassLibrary1.EXE.
> LOG: Attempting download of new URL
> file:///C:/XXXXX/ConsoleApplication1/packages/NUnit.Runners.2.6.3/tools/ClassLibrary1/ClassLibrary1.EXE.
> LOG: Attempting download of new URL
> file:///C:/XXXXX/ConsoleApplication1/packages/NUnit.Runners.2.6.3/tools/lib/ClassLibrary1.EXE.
> LOG: Attempting download of new URL
> file:///C:/XXXXX/ConsoleApplication1/packages/NUnit.Runners.2.6.3/tools/lib/ClassLibrary1/ClassLibrary1.EXE.
> LOG: Attempting download of new URL
> file:///C:/XXXXX/ConsoleApplication1/packages/NUnit.Runners.2.6.3/tools/addins/ClassLibrary1.EXE.
> LOG: Attempting download of new URL
> file:///C:/XXXXX/ConsoleApplication1/packages/NUnit.Runners.2.6.3/tools/addins/ClassLibrary1/ClassLibrary1.EXE.
> LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.

WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly: How come my console app can resolve this assembly by my NUnit test cannot?

**Update 2**

I got the following response from Matlab when I contacted them:

> As far as I know this is the default .NET behavior when it comes to
> deserializations. The application which deserializes the class looks
> for the assembly in its own current folder and GAC where it cannot
> find it. It is similar to (when you read this replace MATLAB with
> Nunit)
>
> http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101695-why-can-my-assembly-not-be-found-when-deserializing-a-net-object-in-matlab-7-10-r2010a
>
> You example does not represent the situation when MATLAB is involved.
> MATLAB sends the class across APPDomains. Your example does not do
> that.
>
> Use Fuslogvw to have a look at the binding.  You will see that it is
> not MATLAB which cannot find the assembly it’s the calling application
> which is unable to resolve the dependency (in your case
> nunit-agent-x86.exe).

Comment: I had the similar behaviour in the GUI NUnit: it couldn't find XML file which is necessary for my DLL working. It happened because NUnit uses *Shadow Copy* by default. At this case NUnit copies my DLL into some temp directory and launches my tests, but it doesn't copy my XML file. Look the *Tools -> Settings... -> Test Loader -> Advanced -> Shadow Copy -> Enable Shadow Copy*. Maybe it is your case also.  When I unchecked this option all works fine, because now NUnit uses my assembly without copying.

Comment: This option value is saved in the *%AppData%\Local\NUnit\NUnitSettings.xml* file (look the `Setting` item with the *"Options.TestLoader.ShadowCopyFiles"* name).

Comment: I've tried turning the Shadow Copy on/off but without any luck.

Comment: Would it be possible to post somewhere a sample project with which we can reproduce the issue ourselves? That way we would be able to only post the answer when we see it really fixes the issue.

Comment: @MichalHosala hmmm that's gonna be kinda tricky. We're locked down here when it comes to emailing posting/code online where I'm working.

Comment: @openshac I see, but from the description it seems to me that it should be possible for you to create a new simple sample project demonstrating the issue. I reckon the only "real" thing would be the .NET assembly built from MATLAB function.

Comment: @MichalHosala yep your right that's going to be the file that I can't get out of the building here.

Comment: make sure that during the loading from the NUnit your dlls keep the original PublicKeyToken.
I had a similar loading issue with some external dlls that required a specific version with that PublicKeyToken and during my execution the PublicKeyToken was set to null...

Answer (score 4):

Make sure all needed files are produced by the compilation of ConsoleApplication4 and placed besides the executable (e.g. any needed assembly DLL, runtime DLL, .config file, etc.)

Once you are sure this happens, start NUnit with the --no-shadow-copy command line switch, or set it as a configuration parameter from your GUI tool. As Bush said, NUnit usually copies the files under test to a separate directory, and may leave behind important files.

If the class created by Matlab needs some sort of specific runtime, make sure it is correctly installed in the computers where you are running the tests / using Excel/ReSharper.

I would not try to fiddle, at this level, with the Assembly resolution process: please sum up the content at the article you linked, because it's paywalled, and try with NUnit's no-shadow-copy setting.

Comment: I cleared the bin\Debug folders of both ConsoleAppliation4 and ClassLibrary1.Tests and re-built both projects. I still get the same exception. I then ran nunit-console-x86 with the /noshadow option and again the exception is the same. I am running the console app and the unit tests on the same machine so I'm happy that the correct assemblies are installed.

Comment: Which .NET Framework does your command line application target?

Comment: I'm using 4.5 since this is required by the version of c# compiled Matlab DLL that I am using. I've tried using the /framework:net-4.0 command line argument with nunit-console-x86.exe but I get the same exception.

Comment: Does NUnit correctly recognize the 4.5 framework? You may try using /framework:net-4.5, and check if anything differs.

Comment: @alex.mazzariol Yep I've tried 4.5 as well, without any difference.

Comment: I'm out of ideas.. In the meanwhile, I found this link you may already know of: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/161601-calling-matlab-from-c-won-t-work-in-unit-tests it seems the problem has been faced by other users too, but still no answer from Mathworks. If you have a support plan, try asking them about this behavior :/

Comment: @alex.mazzariol Yes I did contact Mathworks. I've updated my question with their suggestion.

Comment: Ok, reading the answer it seems a fault in NUnit / ReSharper / Excel... I'd try a dirty road, manually adding both the `AssemblyResolver` event handler and dotnetcli.dll (from Matlab) as a Reference, setting "Local Copy" property to True, so the DLL always follows your assembly. Let me know if this changes the errors, although I'm on an uncharted (afaik) road. As a side question, is it really unfeasible to port your optimization method from Matlab to pure c#?

Comment: @alex.mazzariol I tried adding a reference to dotnetcli.dll but I get the same exception. The whole purpose of this code for me is to wrap an optimization method in Matlab with a C# wrapper so unfortunately it would be unfeasable to port the code to pure C#.

Answer (score 4):

A propos first problem:

1. Run regedit
2. go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fusion
3. Add DWORD ForceLog = 1
4. Add DWORD LogFailures = 1
5. Add DWORD LogResourceBinds = 1
6. Add String LogPath = C:\log\ (last \ must be there)
7. Create a directory for logs (c:\logs for example)

It will log where your app looked for assemblies and how it failed. It probably means that working directory of nunit was different from working directory used by your console application.

A propos second error: *strongly named assembly is required* means that the library you have tried to use was not signed. If it's your assembly you simply have to use visual studio's *sign the assembly* from project properties. If it's not your assembly you can decompile it and compile it with strong name ([with this method](http://buffered.io/posts/net-fu-signing-an-unsigned-assembly-without-delay-signing/)), but provider of third party dll should give you a strong-named assembly.

Comment: My guess this issue comes from an .NET CLR version _incompatibility_.

Comment: I've added the Fusion log as expected it can't find the library ClasLibrary1.dll since it is looking in the NUnit.Runner directory. Obviously it works if I copy the dll to this folder, but that's not really an option for me when I get round to running these tests on the builder server.

Comment: Which assembly are you suggesting I sign? The C# Matlab one or Class1Library.dll?

Comment: @g.pickardou where is thise version incompatibility coming from? And how should I fix it. I have tried setting the framework explicitly with the NUnit command line option.

Comment: Always sign your class libraries - it should take seconds and there is no real reason not to, but according to the log you've posted is the one that yields message about strong signing then your .net just can't find your assembly. If that's the case then consider adding explicit dll paths to your nunit project.

Comment: @RyszardFiński the file it's looking for resides in C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win32. How would my ConsoleApplication resolve this but not my unit test?

Comment: ConsoleApplication has different PATH variable provided. You might use AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AppendPrivatePath to add lookup path to your dll file.

Answer (score 4):

My guess this issue comes from an .NET CLR version *incompatibility*. Some client's (I mean client who *calls* your assembly) loads different versions of the CLE, then the resolved assembly may incompatible with that loaded CLR. This could cause *not* found error, because a compatible assembly really not found.

Try to check/play with both client's versions (the console app) and the server's version (your assembly) and diagnose what is changing.

Also check your assembly reference has "Copy to the output directory" is checked in all projects

Comment: I've tried setting the /framework:net-4.5 setting but it still fails. My ClassLibrary1, ConsoleApplication4 and ClassLibrary1.Test projects are all using version 4.5 of the .Net Framework. I am using project references (not assembly references) and have "Copy Local" set to "True".

Comment: Do you reference the ClassLibrary1.dll in the unit test project?

Comment: Yes I do. Without it I just get a simple "System.IO.FileNotFoundException".

Comment: Incompatibility usually throws BadImageFormatException

Answer (score 3):

You will want to study how the probing operation happens at .NET load time.  Here's the rules for that: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf(v=vs.110).aspx

Outside of including the bin in the assembly you are publishing, it's the loader that decides if the support cast of DLLs are loadable.  If it cannot find it using the rules above then you are simply out of luck.

We have seen issues similar to this in the past, some developer says to system admin, here's the Dlls you need to get the app running.  System Admin follows instructions and boom, the application fails at load time.

Reason: Some child of a child in the assembly referred to a dll that's NOT on the system based on the probing rules.

Solution 
1) Get the (child of the child) dll to include all dependencies in its assembly 
2) Change the newer Main assembly to include all the dependencies (if the children assemblies cannot be changed).
3) Manually copy them in. 
4) Create an installer that does it all.

Comment: OK so from the Fusion log I can see once correct bind to dotnet.cli.dll One log file says "This bind starts in LoadFrom load context." and is successful, the other says "This bind starts in default load context." and is unsuccessful. I also tried specifying the codeBase in the config file but this was unsuccessful.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but folks have a difficult time understanding Loader Failures.  Loader hints happen based on the mainfest of the DLL for .NET modules.  These can be seen using the ILDASM tool.  Any reference in the manifest to "extern" means that this is a DLL that is considered "External" to what is in and known by the assembly.  If that External reference is not in the PROBING paths, the loader will fail.  Start with that, what module is failing.  Then ask yourself; how do I get resolve that dependency for the loader.

Answer (score 2):

Is the assembly in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) or any place the might be overriding the assembly that you think is being loaded? This is usually the result of an incorrect assembly being loaded, for me it means I usually have something in the GAC overriding the version I have in bin/Debug.

Comment: The fusion log reports that the GAC look was unsuccessful so I'm not sure that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

My guess this issue comes from an .NET CLR version incompatibility. Some client's (I mean client who calls your assembly) loads different versions of the CLE, then the resolved assembly may incompatible with that loaded CLR. This could cause not found error, because a compatible assembly really not found.

Try to check/play with both client's versions (the console app) and the server's version (your assembly) and diagnose what is changing.

Also check your assembly reference has "Copy to the output directory" is checked in all projects

Comment: If there is an incompatibility with .Net CLR version, how come it runs if I place the MatLab DLL in the same location as the NUnit test runner? Sure if there was an incompatibilty in the version it would still fail. Have you been able to download the sample project provided?